# Shortcut for dragging and dropping a tab on terminal

Tags: terminal, shortcut, tabs

Not sure if this is possible. But I was wondering if there is a shortcut for physically moving a tab on my Terminal.

Say I have these tabs on my terminal:

```
| tab A | tab B | tab C | tab D |
```

If I were to move from tab A to tab C, I would do `command + ]` or `[` two times.
Well, I'm very lazy, so I would like to just do `command + ]` once. (This becomes especially useful when I have several tabs open) The only way to do that is to have tab C right next to A.

So, I'd like to have tabs in this order:

```
| tab A | tab C | tab B | tab D |
```

My question is, is there any way to get this done with a shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such shortcut in *Terminal* (apart of dragging the tabs manually), however such feature works fine out-of-box in *Term2* by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>.

Another way is to have tabs in separate windows (<kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>)and switch between them by <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd>, etc in order you like.

See also: [Keyboard shortcut to jump between tabs on OS X Terminal](https://superuser.com/q/131903/87805)